# android enum iterating without switch

Tags: android, enums, iteration

I have Enums with Exception number and description. I pass exception number to MessageHandler.
And then i want to handle them and show user message with error description.
What is the best way to itterate over results without using switch construction ?

I have a few solutions but i'm not sure which is better for android.

Thank you.

Comment: I was thinking of keeping my values in this way:
ALL_OK  (0, "no errors"),
SOME_ERROR   (1, "unknow error occured"),
CONNECTION_ERROR(2, "connection "),

to keep everything incapsulated. 
And then to get values depending on number

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a fairly straight-forward way to do this, and to do it in a way that doesn't depend on a particular `enum`. I ran into this problem when wanting to use `enum`s to populate different parts of the UI.

Here is a little bit of sample code to show you how I did it:

```
public int enumPosition(Enum<?> lookingFor, Enum<?>[] lookingIn)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lookingIn.length; i++)
    {
        if (lookingIn[i].getValue().equals(lookingFor.getValue()))
        {
            //Found Answer
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, depending on what you need there are good ways to setup your `enum` to allow for better access and searching, here's what I mean:

```
public enum ExampleEnum
{
firstValue("#1", 1),
secondValue("#2", 2),
thirdValue("#3", 3);

private final String id;
private final int somethingUseful;

ExampleEnum(String id, int usefulValue)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.somethingUseful = usefulValue;
}

public String getValue() { return id; }
public int getSomethingUseful () { return somethingUseful; }

public static ExampleEnumfromString(String text) 
{
    if (text != null)
    {
        for (ExampleEnumt : ExampleEnum.values()) 
        {
            if (text.equalsIgnoreCase(t.id)) 
            {
                  return t;
            }
        }
    }

    //Usually best to throw an exception here
    return ExampleEnum.firstValue;
}


//Useful for passing to adapters
public static String[] getValues() 
{
    String[] vals = new String[ExampleEnum.values().length];
    int i = 0;
    for (ExampleEnumt : ExampleEnum.values()) 
    {
        vals[i] = t.getValue();
        i++;
    }
    return vals;
}

@Override
public String toString() 
{
    return getValue();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;

import com.cyberneticscore.voliastatis.R;

public enum ExceptionEnums {
NO_ERROR(1),
CONNECTION_ERROR(2),
LOGIN_ERROR     (3),
SSL_ERROR       (4),
WRONG_DATE      (5),
INTERRUPTED     (6),
CLIENT_PROTOCOL_ERROR(7),
UNKNOWN_HOST_ERROR(8),
IO_ERROR        (9),
XPATHER_ERROR(10);

private static final Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

private static Context context;
private static Resources reso;

public static void getContext(Context _context)
{
    context =_context;
    reso = context.getResources();
}

private int pos;

public static void putMapValues(){
//static{
    map.put(NO_ERROR.getPos(), reso.getString(R.string.exceptions_no_error));
    map.put(CONNECTION_ERROR.getPos(), reso.getString(R.string.exceptions_connection_error));
    map.put(LOGIN_ERROR.getPos(), reso.getString(R.string.exceptions_login_error)); 
    map.put(SSL_ERROR.getPos(), reso.getString(R.string.exceptions_ssl_error)); 
    map.put(WRONG_DATE.getPos(), reso.getString(R.string.exceptions_wrong_date));
    map.put(INTERRUPTED.getPos(), reso.getString(R.string.exceptions_interrupted));
    map.put(CLIENT_PROTOCOL_ERROR.getPos(), reso.getString(R.string.exceptions_client_protocol_error));
    map.put(UNKNOWN_HOST_ERROR.getPos(), reso.getString(R.string.exceptions_unknown_host_error));
    map.put(IO_ERROR.getPos(), reso.getString(R.string.exceptions_io_error)); 
    map.put(XPATHER_ERROR.getPos(), reso.getString(R.string.exceptions_xpather_error));
}

ExceptionEnums(int pos){
    this.pos = pos;
}

public int getPos(){
    return pos;
}

public static String getErrorDescription(int position_number){
    return map.get(position_number);
}
}
```